# Como identificar categoria por slug ao inserir um registro com wp_insert_post() do wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso identificar as categorias por slug ao adicionar um post no wordpress.

Exemplo comum e funcional:

```
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_title'    => 'titulo',
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_content'  => 'desc',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'tax_input' => array( 
                  'categoria' => array( 
                    '1'  //categoria identificada por ID
                  ) 
                )
            ) );
```

Como eu preciso que fique:

```
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_title'    => 'titulo',
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_content'  => 'desc',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'tax_input' => array( 
                  'categoria' => array( 
                    'filme'  //categoria identificada por slug
                  ) 
                )
            ) );
```

Existe esta possibilidade? O exemplo acima não funcionou pra mim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar [get_term_by()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) para recuperar o ID da categoria.

```php
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'filme', 'categoria' );
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_title'    => 'titulo',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_content'  => 'desc',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'tax_input' => array( 
        'categoria' => array( $term->term_id ) 
    )
) );
```